# Update statement behaviour in Microsoft Access with inner join

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've boiled this problem down as much as I can. When running an Update query in microsoft access, where I have an inner join in the update statement with a one to many relationship, Access does not seem to behave as expected. It is better seen with an example.

I have Table A:

| ClientID | Year | DollarValue | ConvValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1985 | 1000 |  |
| 90 | 1985 | 500 |  |

and Table B, which shares the ClientID and Year columns:

| ClientID | Year | RegionID | ECF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1985 | 3 | 100 |
| 90 | 1985 | 4 | 10 |

And the following query:

```
UPDATE tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON ([tableA].ClientID=[tableB].ClientID) AND ([tableA].Year=[tableB].Year) SET tableA.ConvValue = [tableA]!DollarValue/[tableB]!ECF
```

The resulting tableA looks like this:

| RegionID | Year | ClientID | DollarValue | ConvValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1985 | 90 | 1000 | 100 |
| 4 | 1985 | 90 | 500 | 50 |

When executing the query, the dialog box states that 4 records will be updated, which I assume is due to there being 2 matches in Table B for each row of Table A based on the join condition. What is confusing is the datasheet view of the update query, which looks like this:

| ConvValue |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 100 |
| 50 |
| 50 |

It's clear that only the conversion factor for RegionID 4 is being used - this does not make sense to me, because based on the join conditions I would expect there to be a match for both RegionID 3 and 4, and thus there would be 4 distinct values in the resulting update query. A couple of questions:

Why does the datasheet view of the update query show only one conversion factor being used, when there are two matches in Table B for each row of Table A?

How is Access deciding to update the table, given that the datasheet view contains 4 rows, but there are only 2 rows in the table being updated?

I know that update queries should not be as specific and this will be rewritten, this is just a bug in a database I am working on and wondering why this result is being produced.

Thank you!

Debugging with a select statement

Comment: How should Access know which ECF to use for each record in table A? Apparently, Access SQL engine tries to resolve this confusion but just using the "first" ECF it encounters, which is 10 when sorted ascending. Which ECF would you want used - what do you base your decision on?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't expect access to know which ECF to use, as there are two records in table B which meet the join condition for each row in Table A. I am just confused why Access is deciding to use only one of the ECFs from the matching rows.

Comment: In reality, there are actually only 2 records to be updated. Access must decide for each record what value to update with - in both cases it decides to use 10. Even though query shows 4 records because of Cartesian product, there are only 2 records from table A - the same decision is shown for the 'duplicates'.

Answer (score 1):

Access takes the first record in table A and find the first matching record in table B and updates ConvValue. Then it finds the second matching record in table B for the first record in table A und updates table A again and so on. In the preview you see therefore all record combinations which Access found for updates. As there is a 1:n relation between table A and table B, records in table A will be updated n-times.

This is an absolute logical way and no bug.

Comment: Thanks. But despite there being two matches in Table B for each Table A row, only one ECF is being used, corresponding to RegionID 4. If the preview should show all record combinations, then I would expect the ECF for RegionID 3 to be used as well.

Comment: No, both will be used. But as you change two times the same record, you see just the last change. Which one it is depends on in which order Access pics the records.
example:
First client ID 90 for year 1985 in table A matches the Region 3 in table B based on Client ID and year.. Calculation will be done and saved. Then the same record from A matches Region 4 in table B and the calculation will be saved again in table A and overwrites the calculation result from the first match (Region 3).